# Get user's plain password on registration with FOSUser bundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FosUserBundle to handle my application login/registration workflows. Then I need to obtain the user's plain password on registration, because I would like to generate an access token using the `grant_type=password` workflow with the FOSOAuthServer bundle.

I tried with the following events:

- `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE` : No password here
- `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` : Plain password but no user in database because this event is called right before the user creation
- `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED`: The user is created in the database, but the `$event->getUser()->getPlainPassword()` return null, because on user creation the method `$userManager->updatePassword()` set the `plainPassword` attribute to null

Do you have any secure idea of how can I handle this? I've got to main ideas but I'm not sure if it is the right way to do it:

- Put the password in session on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS` and generate the access token then remove the password on `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED`
- Override the user manager class to make the method `$userManager->updatePassword()` do no call `$userManager->eraseCredentials()` and use it on registration (not surehow to do it)

Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 1):

you can save plainpassword as new parameter on user model (for example as tempPlainPassword parameter ) at event FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS and use it whenever you want!

for security reasons you must empty value of that parameter (tempPlainPassword) after use it ;

```
namespace [someBundle]\UserBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class RegistrationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
    return array(
        FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS => 'onRegistrationSuccess',
    );
    }

    public function onRegistrationSuccess(FormEvent $event)
    {
            $user = $event->getForm()->getData();
           $user->setTempPlainPass($user->getPlainPassword());
    }
}
```